# How to import groups of contact and make it a new group

Tags: groups

I am new in the CiviCRM community! As I am accustomed to closed-source CRM platforms, I have issues finding an answer to my need: I would like to import a group of contacts, and then make it automatically a new group so that I could email them.

It is possible and how?

Thanks,
Mathilde

Comment: You can import contacts and assign them to a group as you are importing. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/#preparing-to-import-data

Comment: @Demerit I believe you could post this as an answer

Comment: Ok thanks. . . . .

Answer (score 2):

You can import contacts and assign them to a group as you are importing. See https://docs.civicrm.org/user/en/latest/common-workflows/importing-data-into-civicrm/#preparing-to-import-data

When creating the Group check the box for "Mailing List" otherwise it won't be available as a group when you go to CiviMail - New Mailing.

Comment: "so that I could email them" means there is one extra step, when creating the Group set to 'Mailing List' otherwise it won't show in CiviMail

Comment: Good point. Will update answer.